# How to SELF join lead table in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

My requirement is to find the duplicate lead for the current lead by matching against all other leads in the database. something like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/439dd/1

I am not sure how the same can be done using SOQL. Can somebody help me on this?

**EDIT:**

Just to clear the confusion. I am not looking for a way to prevent duplicates in the system. My goal is to find duplicate leads for a given lead in a batch job. I am going to use this query in the batch job execute method.

Comment: Dear downvoter, This is the second question you downvoted in two days, not sure what is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you provided

> INNER JOIN Leads SecondTable ON   SecondTable.FirstName =
>   firstTable.FirstName AND   SecondTable.LastName = FirstTable.LastName
>   AND SecondTable.Email = FirstTable.Email

is a match on all three fields so that is easy....

1. Make an external ID field that concatonates the First and lastName fields along with the email and set it to a unique index. Name it say `dupIdx`

Then in the lead trigger it would be something like:

```
trigger findDuplicates on lead(after Insert){

   Map<String,Lead[]> duplicates = New Map<String[]>();

   for(trigger.new l : lead){
       if(dulicates.containsKey(l.dupIdx__c))
           duplicates.get(l.dupIdx__c).add(l); //catches dupes in the trigger
       else
           dulicates.put(l.dupIdx__c,New lead[]);
   }

   for(Lead l : [Select ID, dupIdx__c From Lead Where dupIdx__c IN :duplicates.keyset() AND ID NOT IN :trigger.new]){
      duplicates.get(l.dupIdx__c).add(l);
   }

   //now run through trigger again checking for the dupes and add errors as appropriate


}
```

**If you want to then prevent duplicates, you can make the field unique and case insensitive and then you do not need the trigger at all.**

Comment: Can I do this without creating an extra field on the lead object? I want to do this for selected set of leads in a scheduled batch.

Comment: Actually I want to use this query in this batch job. Here is my other question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88105/how-to-find-duplicate-leads-for-given-set-of-leads

Comment: I take the time to answer your question only to find out that your question is not really the question you wanted to ask....???...And yes you could do this in a batch. Yes you could do it without the field but it introduces unnecessary complexity.....

Comment: No Eric..I am really sorry..I am still looking for query to get duplicate leads but I just don't want to create extra field on the lead object...My sincere apologies for any miscommunication

Comment: Why would you have a problem creating the field? it takes A LOT of the work off of the code with the field present. Otherwise you will have to query the entire database and evaluate OR set a scope size of 1 in the batch and perform a query for each lead.....

Comment: The reason is I am not looking for code to prevent duplicates, I want to find duplicates for given set of leads in a campaign. Can I create this extra field on the already existing leads by combining their first name,lastname etc..

Comment: Even if you just want to find leads, best way it to create the field. It will help to identify and query for leads in a single process....And yes you can add the field to existing leads, you will just have to bulk update them to get the field populated using the workflow.

Comment: Thanks so much @Eric for the answer. I will follow this advice. Again I am sorry regarding the confusion caused..I Hope you understood my intention betwen two questions. I really appreciate your time looking into this. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: No worries, of future, if your question is related to another question at least post a link and say what your are expecting to achieve. No one reading this would have known that this question was related to a batch or another question...

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I deleted my other question that you commented on. I apologize for any inconvenience. Thanks!

Comment: @javanoob - no worries....